# scrbook - How to place chapter to the left edge and section to the right edge on single-sided (!) documents?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

Let's create a single-sided (!) document made in `scrbook`-class (e.g. scientific work) by setting `\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}`.

---

**Working minimum-example:**

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \blinddocument

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the initial state**

Consequently, the chapter will be placed in the middle of the head (on non-plain-pages).

[image]

---

**Screenshot of the desired end state**

But now how is it possible to place the chapters name to the left edge and the sections name to the right edge?

[image]

---

In a two-sided layout it would be really simple by typing...

```
\automark[section]{chapter}       % chapter in \leftmark; section in \rightmark

\lehead[]{\leftmark}{\leftmark}   % \leftmark placed in even-side left-edges
\rohead{\rightmark}               % \rightmark placed in odd-side right-edges
```

... into the preambel. But how does it work for single-sided documents (with declaration `twoside=false`)?

It is a well known fact that popular KOMA-classes like...

`\lehead[content plain.scrheadings]{content scrheadings}
\rehead[content plain.scrheadings]{content scrheadings}`

... only will work fine in double-sided layouts.

---

Thank you very much for your help, I'm curious about your solutions! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use both `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` in a one-sided document with package `scrlayer-scrpage` you have to set the option `autooneside=false`

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[
  automark,
  autooneside=false % <- 
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\rightmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that option `automark` does the same as `\automark[section]{chapter}` and `\cfoot*{\pagemark}` is a short version of `\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}`.

---

**Update**

To avoid identical entries in left and right header you can change the definition of `\ohead` to

```
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[
  automark,
  autooneside=false 
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\chapter{Chapter}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: This almost works absolutely perfect, thank you very much for your help! :::: There is one more (little) question: All directories that span multiple pages now contain the name of the respective directory in `\leftmark` AND in `\rightmark` on all pages following the `plain`-page of chapters headline. That means, for example, that the headline "Table of contents" is shown in `\leftmark` AND in `\rightmark` on all pages behind the chaptertitle-page (what looks a bit crazy because of two identical entries). :::: Is there any option to change the visibility to only one entry (for all directories)?

Comment: Better I'd simply could ask ***How to avoid duplicate-headings in header of multipage bibliographies (of single-sided documents)?*** Is there any option to unactivate `\leftmark` or at least `\rightmark` exclusively in `\tableofcontents`, `listofffigures`, `\listofftables` or `\printglossary`?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Wow, LaTeX rocks - this command is really making sense! Thank you very much for your great help! Before, I thought that I have to exclude the bibliographies from the automark-command or something like that... Perfect! :-)